# Array length handling when serializing messages

Tags: rosbag, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to code a rosbag serializer, and I am trying to generate code from the messages, like https://github.com/ros/genmsg

I noticed there's an inconsitency in how to handle unbounded array lengths.

In some cases, it is assumed the array elements are preceded with the length of the array: CameraInfo

In some others, the length is calculated from other properties of the message: Image, PointCloud2

Then there's cases in which it's not clear if the length needs to be handled based on the length of the whole message itself: CompressedImage.

So, are these cases handled manually? or is there some sort of non obvious rule?

I have noticed that in the definitions of some unbounded arrays, it is stated that the length needs to be computed from other parameters.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306038/array-length-handling-when-serializing-messages/) by [Vicente Penades](https://answers.ros.org/users/38071/vicente-penades/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2018-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The serialization logic only considers the length of the actual array.

Any other fields in a message containing such length information are additionally information and might (or might not) match the actual data. They are serialized independently.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0